# Using ERB inside Script Tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do some fairly simple jQuery inside `script` tags on my Rails app (I know, bad developer, no cookie, don't use script tags) and am having trouble with the erb-generated ids.  I have the following in my view:

```
        <% @clients_with_pricing.each do |client| %>
            <h3 id="client-<%= client.id %>-header"><%= client.first_name %> <%= client.last_name %></h3>
            <div id="client-<%= client.id %>-div">
                <h4><%= client.company_name %></h4>
                <ul>
                    <% client.pricings.each do |pricing| %>
                        <li><%= number_to_currency(pricing.price, precision: 0) %>: <%= pricing.product.name %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- client id div -->
        <% end %>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.client-<&= client.id %>-header').click(function(){
            $('.client-<&= client.id %>-div').toggleClass('hidden');
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I look at the rendered HTML the ids get generated properly, but the jQuery still has the erb in it.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for ERB is `<%` and `<%=`. Change `<&=` to `<%=` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that glaringly obvious typo *shame* and am now getting a console error: `jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:1503 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .client-<&= client.id %>-header`

Comment: Hmm, is this code inline in your erb file, or in a separate javascript file?

Comment: It's inline in my html.erb file.

Answer (score 3):

`var name = "<%= j @name %>";`